# Combining 2 rasters using Con and IsNull in Python

Tags: python, raster, nodata, con

I am trying to write a Python script that converts most NoData pixels to 0 in a raster (Raster1 below), except for pixels that overlap with a pixel value of 1 within another raster (Raster2, which has pixels that are either 0 or 1). I am therefore trying to combine `Con` and `IsNull` in the following statement, where Raster1 is the raster whose NoData pixels should be converted to 0, and Raster2 is raster containing the values 0 and 1:

```
Con(((IsNull(Raster1)) & (Raster2==0)), 0, Raster1)
```

The output raster is correctly converting NoData pixels to 0, but it’s not completing the 2nd part of the condition, which specifies that a pixel in raster1 should only be converted to 0 if both the raster1 pixel is NoData *and* Raster2 pixel=1.

I have a workaround where I develop the `Con` statement without the Raster2 portion of the argument, and then multiply this output by a mask. However, I worry that this would take a lot longer to process, as the rasters I’m working with are huge. I’m also trying to understand how to use the `Con` statement more, and I’m confused why this is not working.

My rasters are TIFFs, although I do perform a step earlier in the script that converts a mosaic to a TIFF. I don’t see how this would be causing the problem, but I’ve included the full script below just in case (the `Con` statement is in the last section of the script):

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Variables
inWS = r"G:\ellie\_testing_script\mosaics.gdb" # UPDATE
outWS = r"G:\ellie\_testing_script\out_TIFs" # UPDATE
Raster2 = r"G:\ellie\MosaicExports\GAP\GAPStatus12_All" # UPDATE
scratch = r"G:\ellie\_testing_script\scratch" # UPDATE
print ("Variables Set")

# Environments 
env.workspace = inWS 
arcpy.env.snapRaster = "G:\\ellie\\SnapRaster\\NLCD_2011_USGS_LandCover_AlbConEA_16bitU.tif" 
env.overwriteOutput = True print ("Environments Set")

# Create list of mosaics in Geodatabase 
mosaics = `arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Mosaic")`

# Loop through mosaics in geodatabase: for mosaic in mosaics:
    print("Processing " + mosaic)
    # We aren't using the GAP123 inputs, so don't process those:
    if mosaic.startswith("RSR_GAP123"):
        pass
    else:
        # Loop through mosaics (not GAP123) to export to new TIF raster
        inMosaic = inWS + "\\"  + mosaic
        # outName needs to be determined by the 2nd "_" argument in order to change some output filenames
        second_argument = mosaic.split('_')[1]
        last_arguments = mosaic[10:]
        if second_argument == "GAP12":
            outName = "PWRSR_GAP12_" + last_arguments + ".tif"
        else:
            outName = mosaic + ".tif"
        arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(inMosaic, scratch, outName,"", "32_BIT_FLOAT", "", "1", "LAST", "FIRST")
        print(outName + " exported as TIF. Converting NAs to 0s...")

        # Convert NA to 0s, except for PAs
        Raster1 = scratch + "\\" + outName
        outCon = Con(((IsNull(Raster1)) & (Raster2==0)), 0, Raster1)
        print(outName + " NAs converted to 0s. Saving raster...")
        outCon.save(outWS + "\\" + outName)

print ("Finished")
```